# How to use pure CSS to get a specified HTML content into fixed width and height element?

Tags: css

In this picture, I have a HTML content "div#container". It may contain a lot of things like images, forms and other HTML tags.

I want to resize this div and put it inside other container(s). The new containers may have different widht/height so I have to resize the `div#container`. It's a bit like to resize an image - I need to keep the width/height ratio. And I need to place the div#container in the center of the new container.

Is it to do so with pure CSS?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you want to keep a specific aspect ratio for your container you will need to set @media sizes based on the widths you want and size the container appropriately. You can [read more about it here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: are you opposed to using padding? I have a solution that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it using `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` on `div#container` and `padding` on `div#dash-container`:

```css
.container {
    background: lightgray;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.dash-container-1,
.dash-container-2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: dashed 2px;
}
.dash-container-1 {
    height: 500px; /*whatever sizes you want*/
    width: 300px;
    padding: 100px 0;
}
.dash-container-2 {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 0 5%; //you can use px, %, em, ...
}
```

```html
<div class="dash-container-1">
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
<div class="dash-container-2">
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/do22veyz/ not working well.... why set the padding to 100px? I hope the solution can be applied to all cases.

Comment: `padding: 100px` is just a suggested number. You can use `%` or `em` also. See my update. Either way you are gonna have to specify no top/bottom padding for wide containers and no left/right padding for thin containers.